# Compounds with high electron density

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrons

If $d$ is the ratio of the total number of electrons in a compound and the average radius(of all anions and cations, or covalent radii), are there known compounds (inorganic or organic) where $d$ is high?

Are there any rules or analytic techniques to design such compounds that have stable chemistry?

Please don't confuse the electron density in the title to [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_density)

**Edit:** Assume the constraint that we want common elements and no exotic, radioactive ones.

Comment: Your d is high where the atomic number is high.

Comment: @IvanNeretin: Edited. Consider the effect of average radius as well.

Comment: I still stand by my statement.

Answer (score 1):

Mercury has 80 electrons and a [covalent radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_radius) of 132 picometers.